# Converter int ou string para enum

Tags: c#, conversão-de-tipo, enums

Como converter variáveis dos tipos `int` e `string` para um `enum`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Converter int para `enum`

```
var meuInteiro = 0;    
MinhaEnum foo = (MinhaEnum)meuInteiro;
// foo == MinhaEnum.Primeiro
```

Converter string para enum

```
var minhaString = "Segundo";
MinhaEnum foo = (MinhaEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MinhaEnum), minhaString);
// foo == MinhaEnum.Segundo
```

Exemplo com conversão inválida usando `string`, como citado pelo @Maniero

```
var minhaString = "Terceiro";
MinhaEnum foo = (MinhaEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MinhaEnum), minhaString);
// Será disparada uma exceção
// Additional information: Valor 'Terceiro' solicitado não foi encontrado.
```

Para evitar uma exceção (quando não se tem certeza que o valor da *string* corresponde a um valor da enum), podemos utilizar o método [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var minhaString = "Segundo";
MinhaEnum foo;
// Se o valor da string corresponder ao Enum, enumValida será True
// e o valor será atribuido a varíavel foo
var enumValida = Enum.TryParse<MinhaEnum>(minhaString, out foo);
if (enumValida)
    Console.WriteLine(foo);// foo == MinhaEnum.Segundo
else
    Console.WriteLine("A string informada não corresponde ao enumerador.");
// Caso o valor da string não corresponda à Enum, foo terá o valor padrão da Enum
// nesse caso, foo == MinhaEnum.Primeiro
```

Exemplo de enumerador

```
public enum MinhaEnum
{
    Primeiro = 0,
    Segundo = 1
}
```

Pergunta já respondida no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Partindo do princípio que a *string*, tem um valor válido.

Comment: Só queria deixar uma contribuição, em vez de usar `var` use o tipo de cada dado isso vai trazer clareza no código e padrão. O uso do `var` dessa forma para usuários inexperiente ou/e iniciantes pode trazer confusão. Só uma dica construtiva.